# SELECT проблема с WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

Составил запрос на тех кто вчера был:

```
SELECT t2.Full_Name 
FROM monitoring t1 
INNER JOIN employee t2 ON t1.id_employee = t2.id_employee 
WHERE TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(entrance) = 1 GROUP BY t1.id_employee
```

Не могу переделать на запрос, который выводил бы тех, кого только вчера не было. Если менять знаки сравнения то выводит и тех кто был позавчера и т.д.

[image: Приклыдваю структуру таблицы]

1. 3
   1
   2018-04-28 09:00:00
   2018-04-28 13:00:00
2. 4
   1
   2018-04-28 14:00:00
   2018-04-28 18:00:00
3. 5
   2
   2018-04-28 10:03:00
   2018-04-28 13:00:00
4. 6
   2
   2018-04-28 15:00:00
   2018-04-28 18:00:00
5. 7
   3
   2018-04-29 09:00:00
   2018-04-29 18:00:00
6. 8
   1
   2018-04-27 09:00:00
   2018-04-27 18:00:00
7. 9
   3
   2018-04-27 09:00:00
   2018-04-27 13:00:00
8. 10
   3
   2018-04-27 14:00:00
   2018-04-27 18:00:00

Comment: Могли бы вы привести пример данных в текстовом виде?

Comment: @0xdb Добавил данные в текстовом виде

Comment: Тут поможет только вычитание из полного списка тех кто вчера был

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис Получается надо после where селектить id_ employee по вчерашней дате? И потом как то полученные айдишники сверять со всеми которые есть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.Full_Name
FROM employee t2
WHERE t2.id_employee
NOT IN (
SELECT t2.id_employee 
FROM monitoring t1 
INNER JOIN employee t2 ON t1.id_employee = t2.id_employee 
WHERE TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(entrance) = 1 
) GROUP BY t2.id_employee
```

Возможно неправильно, но идея примерно такая.

Comment: Верно работает, только после Group By должно быть t2.id_employee. Иначе компилятор на несуществующий столбец ругается